# junit wait until external resource is ready

Tags: java, junit, cassandra

I am trying to test Cassandra with JUnit External resources. I have two classes CassandraExternalResource and TestCassandra. Here is snippet from TestCassandra:

```
    public class TestCassandra {

        @Rule
        public CassandraExternalResource cassandraExternalResource = new CassandraExternalResource();


        @Test
        public void test() throws InterruptedException {
            System.out.println("During Test");
        }
    }
```

In before method of CassandraExternalResource I start Cassandra Server with a separate thread. What I want is to make test cases wait until cassandra server is up and running.

Since server takes some time to start, test cases start to run before server is ready.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the rule's before method by pinging the cassandra server until it is ready.

Comment: How can I understand Cassandra server is ready and since I start Cassandra with a separate thread how can I ping until the server is ready?

Comment: It depends on the definition of "ready". You can try to connect to cassandra, until you get a connection.